# Python exchangelib raise ValueERROR datetime_received

Tags: python, outlook, exchangelib

I'm trying to check how many emails have been received from the specified `sender.email_address` the past 24 hours, but I get an error from this code

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:/Users/fmi/Desktop/Python/emailtest.py", line 13, in 
> for item in testfolder.all()
> File "C:\Users\fmi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\queryset.py", line 507, in order_by
> raise ValueError("%s in order_by()" % e.args[0])
> ValueError: Unknown field path '-datetime_recieved' on folders [Messages(Root(<exchangelib.account.Account object at 0x020A81F0>, '[self]', 'root', 8, 0, 62, None, 'AQMkADI2YmY4MjAwAC1mNTBkLTQyMzEtYTM0Yi04NTdmZDRhMDE0MGQALgAAA+xnYBMGPANEmpY/yEHuM6wBAEYSp+OGVQhHl3U8WgJ/ZQAAAwEBAAAAAA==', 'AQAAABYAAABGEqfjhlUIR5d1PFoCf2UAAAAcRKyn'), 'Test', 26821, 26654, 0, 'IPF.Note', 'AQMkADI2YmY4MjAwAC1mNTBkLTQyMzEtYTM0Yi04NTdmZDRhMDE0MGQALgAAA+xnYBMGPANEmpY/yEHuM6wBAEYSp+OGVQhHl3U8WgJ/ZQAAAw0rAAAA', 'AQAAABYAAABGEqfjhlUIR5d1PFoCf2UAAAAcRKxr')] in order_by()

when trying to print. I also want it to give me an alert if the email count is 0.

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account, UTC_NOW
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import timedelta

credentials = Credentials('fmi@.dk', 'something')
a = Account('fmi@.dk', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)
counts = defaultdict(int)
testfolder = a.inbox.parent / 'Test'
since = UTC_NOW() - timedelta(hours=24)

for item in testfolder.all()\
        .only('sender', 'subject')\
        .filter(datetime_received__gt=since)\
        .order_by('-datetime_received'):
    if item.sender.email_address == 'info@something.dk':
        counts[item.sender.email_address, item.subject] += 1 
print(counts)
```

Comment: Which kind of folder is `testfolder`? Check with `print(testfolder.folder_class, testfolder.__class__)`. My only suggestion would be that the dash in  `-datetime_received` is somehow not the standard ASCII character 45 (dash).

Comment: IPF.Note <class 'exchangelib.folders.known_folders.Messages'> is the output from the print - I tried without the dash, however I had the same issue.@ErikCederstrand I edited my post with the full traceback.

Comment: I have no idea what happend, but now the code suddenly works.